# Partition table based on joined table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have 2 Tables Lead and Task.
One lead can have multiple Tasks.
We want to determine if a Lead has a Task who's description contains String 'x'.

If the Lead has the String the it should belong to group1 if it doesn't to group2.

Then we want to count the leads per group and week.
The problem we have is that if a Lead has several tasks and one of them has string 'x' in its description and the others don't it is counted in both groups.

We would need something that resembles a break; statement in the IFF clause of the subquery, so that if the first condition = Contain string x is satisfied the other tasks are not counted anymore.
How would we achieve that?

So far we have the following statement:
--SQL:

```
SELECT LeadDate, GROUP, COUNT(LEAD_ID_T1)
FROM LEAD Lead INNER JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT LEAD.ID AS LEAD_ID_T1,
                      IFF(CONTAINS(Task.DESCRIPTION,
                                   'x'),
                          'GROUP1',
                          'GROUP2') AS GROUP
               FROM TASK Task
                        RIGHT JOIN LEAD ON TASK.WHO_ID = LEAD.ID
               ) T1 ON T1.LEAD_ID_T1 = LEAD.ID
GROUP BY LeadDate,GROUP;
```

Code breaks because it can not aggregate the measures.

Really thankful for any input. This has been bothering me for a few days now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking `EXISTS` with a `CASE` expression:

```
select l.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from task t
                          where t.who_id = l.id and
                                t.description like '%x%'
                         )
             then 'GROUP1' else 'GROUP2'
        end) as the_group
from lead l;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this, `CASE` with 1 and 0 then take the `SUM`

```
SELECT LeadDate, 
sum(CASE When  t.description like '%x%'then 1 else 0 end) as Group1,
sum(CASE When  t.description like '%x%'then 0 else 1 end) as Group2
FROM TASK t
RIGHT JOIN LEAD l ON t.WHO_ID = l.ID
GROUP BY LeadDate;
```